# hibernate could not extract resultset

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In a spring mvc web application using hibernate and MySQL, I have a many to many relationship between `Encounter` and `Provider` entities. In a jsp, I need for the user to select the `providers` for a specific `encounter`.  The select box in the jsp thus has to be populated by a list of all `providers`, so that the user can select some number or `providers`.  However, when I try to set this up, I am getting a hibernate error message saying it cannot extract the result set because `provider_id` is not in the field list.  I am trying to differentiate between the `providers` associated with an individual `encounter` versus the list of `allproviders` in the entire database, but I am not sure if I am setting it up correctly.  Can someone show me how to resolve this error?

Here is Encounter.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "encounters")
public class Encounter extends BaseEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
    private Patient patient;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "encountercode")
    private CPTCode cptcode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "office_id")
    private FacilityAddress location;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="encounters")
    protected Set<Provider> providers = new HashSet<Provider>();

    @Column(name="start_date")
    private Date startdate;

    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;

    protected void setPatient(Patient patient) {this.patient = patient;}
    public Patient getPatient(){return this.patient;}

    public void setEncountercode(CPTCode cptc) {this.cptcode = cptc;}
    public CPTCode getEncountercode() {return this.cptcode;}

    public FacilityAddress getLocation(){return location;}
    public void setLocation(FacilityAddress fa){location=fa;}

    public Date getStartdate(){return startdate;}
    public void setStartdate(Date sd){startdate=sd;}

    public String getStatus(){return status;}
    public void setStatus(String st){status=st;}

    public void addProvider(Provider p) {providers.add(p);}
    public Set<Provider> getProviders(){return this.providers;}
    public void setProviders(Set<Provider> ps){this.providers = ps;}

    public boolean isNew() {return (this.id == null);}
}
```

Here is BaseEntity.java:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;

    public void setId(Integer id) {this.id = id;}

    public Integer getId() {return id;}

    public boolean isNew() {return (this.id == null);}
}
```

Here is EncounterController.java:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("encounter")
public class EncounterController {

    private final ClinicService clinicService;

    @Autowired
    public EncounterController(ClinicService clinicService) {this.clinicService = clinicService;}

    @ModelAttribute("encountercodes")
    public Collection<CPTCode> populateEncountercodes() {return this.clinicService.findEncountercodes();}

    @ModelAttribute("allproviders")
    public Collection<Provider> populateAllproviders() {return this.clinicService.findProviders();}

    @InitBinder
    public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initCreationForm(@PathVariable("patientId") int patientId, Map<String, Object> model) {
        Patient patient = this.clinicService.findPatientById(patientId);
        Encounter encounter = new Encounter();
        patient.addEncounter(encounter);
        model.put("encounter", encounter);
        return "encounters/createOrUpdateEncounterForm";
    }

    //THIS IS THE METHOD THAT HANDLES THE FORM
    @RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processCreationForm(@ModelAttribute("encounter") Encounter encounter, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        new EncounterValidator().validate(encounter, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "encounters/createOrUpdateEncounterForm";
        } else {
            this.clinicService.saveEncounter(encounter);
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:/patients?patientID={patientId}";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/{encounterId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initUpdateForm(@PathVariable("encounterId") int encounterId, Map<String, Object> model) {
        System.out.println("--------------------------------- made it into initUpdateForm() method");
        Encounter encounter = this.clinicService.findEncounterById(encounterId);
        model.put("encounter", encounter);
        return "encounters/createOrUpdateEncounterForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/{encounterId}/edit", method = {RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String processUpdateForm(@ModelAttribute("encounter") Encounter encounter, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        new EncounterValidator().validate(encounter, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {return "encounters/createOrUpdateEncounterForm";}
        else {
            this.clinicService.saveEncounter(encounter);
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:/patients?patientID={patientId}&type=enc";
        }
    }
}
```

Provider.java is [at this link](http://jmp.sh/v/V7UBUQk8fqt8fRyXJnSw).

Provider extends Person, which is:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Person extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

public void setFirstName(String fname) {this.firstName = fname;}
public String getFirstName() {return this.firstName;}

public void setLastName(String lname) {this.lastName = lname;}
public String getLastName() {return this.lastName;}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ToStringCreator(this)
    .append("lastName", this.getLastName())
    .append("firstName", this.getFirstName())
    .toString();
}

}
```

The definition SQL includes the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS providerEncounterJunction(
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  provider_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  encounter_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (provider_id) REFERENCES providers(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (encounter_id) REFERENCES encounters(id)
)engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS providerSpecialtiesJunction(
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  provider_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  specialty_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (provider_id) REFERENCES providers(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (specialty_id) REFERENCES providerSpecialties(id)
);
```

ClinicServiceImpl.findProviders() is:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Collection<Provider> findProviders() throws DataAccessException {return providerRepository.findProviders();}
```

JpaProviderRepositoryImpl.findProviders() is:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Provider> findProviders() {
    System.out.println(" in JpaEncounterRepository.findCodes() ");
    List<Provider> myproviders = this.em.createQuery("SELECT pr FROM Provider pr ORDER BY pr.lastName").getResultList();
    return myproviders;
}
```

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'providerti0_.provider_id' in 'field list'
INFO  DefaultLoadEventListener - HHH000327: Error performing load command :   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet  
WARN  warn - Handler execution resulted in exception
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:635) ~[spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106) ~[spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.util.CallMonitoringAspect.invoke(CallMonitoringAspect.java:80) ~[CallMonitoringAspect.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy43.findProviders(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.service.ClinicServiceImpl.findProviders(ClinicServiceImpl.java:197) ~[ClinicServiceImpl.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy46.findProviders(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.web.EncounterController.populateAllproviders(EncounterController.java:55) ~[EncounterController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.invokeModelAttributeMethods(ModelFactory.java:123) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:97) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:722) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73) [datatables-core-0.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71) [datatables-servlet2-0.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_29]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2036) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1815) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2117) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3927) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1092) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1019) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:648) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1107) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:963) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.repository.jpa.JpaProviderRepositoryImpl.findProviders(JpaProviderRepositoryImpl.java:87) ~[JpaProviderRepositoryImpl.class:na]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.repository.jpa.JpaProviderRepositoryImpl.findProviders(JpaProviderRepositoryImpl.java:1) ~[JpaProviderRepositoryImpl.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'providerti0_.provider_id' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2323) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    ... 123 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the Provider entity?

Comment: @DavidLevesque I just added a link to `Provider` in my original posting above, along with `Person`, which is extended by `Provider`.  What else do you need?

Comment: The error you get usually means that your database schema is not in sync with your mappings. Is there really a column named `provider_id` in table `providerEncounterJunction` and in table `providerSpecialtiesJunction`?

Comment: @DavidLevesque I just added the code for `providerEncounterJunction` and `providerSpecialtiesJunction` above.  They both have a `provider_id`. Is there anything else I can show you to identify the source of the problem?

Comment: Did you actually check in the database itself?

Comment: Can you post the code for `ClinicService.findProviders()`?

Comment: @DavidLevesque Yes, I just manually checked the database and those tables include provider_id.  I also just added the method you requested, along with the method called by the method you requested.  Thank you for looking into this.  Is there anything else I can upload?

Comment: Check for `provider_id` in table `providerOfficeJunction`. Also I suggest you do a full text search in your java code to find all occurences of the string `provider_id`, to see if you find anything suspicious (e.g. a copy/paste error in some other entity). That's all I can think of.

Comment: You can also log the SQL statements by adding `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>` in your persistence.xml. Looking at the actual SQL would help to locate the issue.

Comment: @DavidLevesque I did Ctrl-H in eclipse and set `provider_id` as the search criteria and it only returned references in `Patient`, `Provider`, `ProviderEmail`, `ProviderTitle` classes. How can I find my persistence xml? This app is built up from spring petclinic sample, which does not use that file name.

Comment: Sorry, I give up. I don't have more time. Good luck.